# Why Math.atan2 uses such a strange convention?

Tags: javascript, math

Math.atan2 uses a convention for angle that starts at -pi/2 at right, increasing til pi/2 at the same point. The usual angle notation we see in most math works starts at 0 at right, and counter-clockwise increases til pi*2 at the same point.

```
        usual   Math.atan2(y,x)
right   0/2*pi  -2/2*pi
top     1/2*pi  -1/2*pi
left    2/2*pi  0
down    3/2*pi  1/2*pi
```

This is not just unusual, but inconsistent with the other trigonometric functions. Why? Is there any problem if I define my own `atan2` that works the way I'm used to?

Comment: I just put some sample data into a console, and got your usual results as outputs.  Where are you trying this javascript?  http://labs.codecademy.com/BX5n#:workspace.

Edit: actually, it's not quite your usual convention, but it's the one I normally see.  In the maths I do, I usually get -pi < x <= pi for angles in radians

Answer (score 4):

What you call "usual" is not usual at all, just something you learn in high school. It in no way defines what we're "supposed" to get back from trigonometric functions in programming languages. You also learn that the x/y coordinate (0,0) is in the center of your graph, rather than the top left corner as every graphics programming language ever invented will give you =)

The atan2 function isn't actually a true function, it's a special programming thing. It's not the `atan`, it's the "improved version of the atan function", and gives us the angle between a vector (defined by it's dy/dx values) and the horizontal.

You don't need to convert the result to what you're used to, you need to get used to how programming languages work with trigonometry. Plugging the angle that you get back from atan2 into your code knowing this means it'll do exactly what you'd expect. `atan2` gives you the angle between a vector and the horizontal, and has nothing (well... very little) to do with the `atan` function =)

Answer (score 3):

Conventions by definition don't need a reason.  They just need to be consistent.

But one reason the convention makes sense is symmetry.  Symmetrical ranges often simplify code.

For example, `atan2` is frequently used to compute "turn angles".  I.e. You have one vector (say the direction you want a car to go) expressed in the coordinate system of another (a vector along the current direction the car is traveling).  Then `atan2` of the coordinates produces an angle that is a left turn if positive, a right turn if negative, and zero if straight ahead.  And the magnitude gives you the "hardness" of the turn.  A 0..2pi range doesn't have these nice qualities.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple and intuitive.

In standard math, your y coordinate is negative when down, positive when up.  For computer screen coordinates, your y coordinate is positive when down, negative when up.  So effectively you flip Y across the horizontal axis when going from standard math coordinates to screen coordinates.  X coordinate stays the same.

Now take the angles along the circle as defined by atan2 in standard math.  Flip those angles over the horizontal axis, and signs for clockwise and counterclockwise reverse.  So in fact it's not an issue of atan2, but a difference in the convention of whether Y is positive when going up or when going down when defining your coordinate system.  Apparently Math.atan2 chose screen coordinate convention rather than theoretical math convention for its coordinate system, and the reason for that should be obvious given its most common uses.  The Matlab programming language, on the other hand, uses standard math convention for coordinate system and atan2, which again is appropriate given its most common uses.